# Safari on Windows won't play audio

Tags: html, audio, safari

I have audio tags on a website that plays fine in IE 9, FF, and Chrome.  It also plays fine on Safari on an iPad.  But I just downloaded Safari onto my Win 7 / 64 bit machine and cannot get it to play audio.

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('english').play()">ENGLISH
<audio id="english">
     <source  src="/Content/Audio/Parachute/T1S2(En).ogg"/>
     <source  src="/Content/Audio/Parachute/T1S2(En).mp3" />
     <source  src="/Content/Audio/Parachute/T1 Parachutes.wav"/>
</audio>
</a>
```

I have tried adding type="audio/mpeg" to the mp3 for Safari support:

```
<source  src="/Content/Audio/Parachute/T1S2(En).mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
<source  src="/Content/Audio/Parachute/T1S2(En).mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
```

but that still won't play.  I threw the .wav file in there as a last resort, but it will still not play.  I do not have Quicktime installed on my machine and was hoping not to have to download it as I imagine not every user has Quicktime.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: this isnt a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the fix on Windows, Quicktime is required and you have to put the mp3 first.

For the fix on Safari, it is required that the type be set on the mp3, so

```
type="audio/mp3"
```

That has cleared it up on all version of Mac / Safari and Win / Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but when I add :

```
type = "audio/mp3"
```

So, my problem didn´t disappear in Safari. I have win7